# clicking child of Listview in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I have a ListView. The row has three TextViews: textView1, textView2, textView3. Each TextView is clickable, and each results in a different action. So if my ListView has 10 rows, and a user clicks on textView3 of row # 5, how can I tell this apart?

**Update:**

I am thinking along the line

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) { ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you created your own `ListAdapter`. In its `getView()` you can call `setTag()` on each `TextView` to set the row position and set an `OnClickListener` for it. In the listener you can then get the tag for the row number and the id to identify the particular `TextView` in the row.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Clicking on Item use OnClick on Individaul TextView
Call SetOnClickListener on each TextView and also set the ID of TextView. Inside onClick Chek the Id first then Do your Work

```
View.onClickListner onlcick = new   View.onClickListner(){
             public void onClick(View view) {

     switch (view.getId()) {

            case R.id.messages_button1 :
            // Work     
            break;

            case R.id.messages_button2 :
            // Work     
            break;

     }
    }
   }
```

Comment: Does this go inside the adapter or inside the partial function I show above?